# Question on construction of Product Measure,

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

As part of constructing product measure one shows that the measure of a rectangle is well defined.

The standard way to do this is to show that no matter how the rectangle is written, its measure is the same.

Normally the proof involves using indicator functions and integration but I feel this is not satisfactory because in a sense product measures are more fundamental then integration(one can be defined without the other).

I want a proof that doesn't use integration or the MCT.

Anyone have ideas?